# Unable to access variables after creating a daemon thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

This is my first program in threading and I am completely new to OS concepts. I was just trying to understand how to asynchronously do stuffs using python. I am trying to establish a a session and send Keepalives on a daemon thread and send protocol messages using the Main Thread. However I noticed that once I created the thread I am unable to access the variables which I was able to access before creating thread. I do not see the global variables that I used to see before I created this new thread.

Can some one help me understand how threading is working here. I am trying to understand:

- How to print properly so that logging is useful.
- How to kill the thread that we created?
- How to access variables from one thread

  ```
  def pcep_init(ip):
      global pcc_client,keeppkt,pkt,thread1
      accept_connection(ip)
      send_pcep_open()

      # Create new Daemon thread to send KA
      thread1 = myThread(1, "Keepalive-Thread\r")
      thread1.setDaemon(True)

      # Start new Threads
      print "This is thread1 before start %r" % thread1
      thread1.start()
      print "This is thread1 after start %r" % thread1
      print "Coming out of pcep_init"
      return 1
  ```

However when I executed the API i see that the print is not kind of misaligned due to async

```
>>> ret_val=pcep_init("192.168.25.2"). 
starting pce server on 192.168.25.2 port 4189
connection from ('192.168.25.1', 42352)
, initial daemon)>fore start <myThread(Keepalive-Thread
, started daemon 140302767515408)>ead(Keepalive-Thread
Coming out of pcep_init
>>> Starting Keepalive-Thread <------ I am supposed to hit the enter button to get the python prompt not sure why thats needed.

>>> thread1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'thread1' is not defined

>>> threading.currentThread()
<_MainThread(MainThread, started)>
>>> threading.activeCount()
2
>>> threading.enumerate() <-------------- Not sure why this is not showing the Main Thread
, started daemon 140302767515408)>], <myThread(Keepalive-Thread
>>>
```

Comment: For printing issues you may could use the [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#thread-safety) module.

Comment: May also tell us what do you want to do. Maybe there is a framework or library which already implements your problem.

Comment: Thanks I will look into the logging module to see how it works. I am just trying to learn a real time implementation of threading. I am using scapy as the framework to send/receive the messages. Its just that I wanted to do stuffs in parallel.